# ¿Por qué mi disparador en SQL Server al ahora de ejecutarse marca un error de evaluación?

Tags: sql-server

En una base de datos cree dos tablas 1. personas y 2. auxiliar, cree un procedimiento almacenado mediante de una transacción. Sucede que cuando se ejecuta el disparador el primer valor si se inserta en ambas tablas, pero cuando creo otra inserccion me marca un error de evaluación en el disparador (evalúa la FK de personas dos veces en la tabla auxiliar).

Si el error está en el Tigger ¿como puedo solucionarlo?

```
--create database clase;
--use clase;

--create table personas 
--(
--ID char (8)primary key,
--Nombre varchar (50) not null,
--Paterno varchar (50) not null,
--Materno varchar (50) not null,
--Sexo varchar (50) not null,
--Edad int 
--)

--create procedure USP_InNewPerson
--@ID char (8),
--@Nombre varchar(50),
--@Paterno varchar (50),
--@Materno varchar(50),
--@Sexo varchar (50),
--@Edad int

--As

-- Begin tran TrInPersonas
--   Insert into personas Values (@ID,@Nombre,@Paterno,@Materno,@Sexo,@Edad)
--   IF @@ERROR<>0 GOTO verError  COMMIT TRAN
--  RETURN(0)
--  verError:  ROLLBACK TRAN  RETURN (-1)
--go




--create table auxiliar 
--(
--ID char (8)primary key,
--Nombre varchar (50) not null,
--Edad int,
--Palabra varchar (50) not null
--)

create trigger add_aux on personas 
after insert 
as 
Declare @ID char (8), @Nombre varchar(50),@Edad int,@Palabra varchar (50)
 set @ID=(select ID From personas); 
 set @Nombre=(select Nombre From personas);
 set @Edad=(select Edad From personas);

 if(@Edad<18)
    set @Palabra='Es menor de edad';
 else 
    set @Palabra='Es mayor de edad';

 insert into auxiliar values(@ID,@Nombre,@Edad,@Palabra)
go


``
```

Comment: puedes postear el mensaje de error?

Comment: En todo caso, ya hay un problema porque estás haciendo un `SET @ID = (SELECT algo FROM personas)`, cuando la tabla personas tiene más de 1 fila de datos

Comment: El error es: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure add_aux, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 2]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated

Comment: el problema es que lo que te digo, no puedes setear los valores de tus variables de la forma que lo estás haciendo...eso solo sirve cuando hay una fila de datos en la tabla

Comment: Entonces ¿Cuál seria la sintaxis?

Answer (score 3):

El problema puntual, ya te lo menciono Lamak, este tipo de construcción:

```
set @ID=(select ID From personas);
```

estas queriendo inicializar una variable escalar (que solo puede contener un único valor) con el conjunto de todos los `ID` de la tabla `personas` que seguramente es una tabla que tiene más de un registro. Por supuesto hay forma de resolverlo, por ejemplo solo filtrando LA persona que estás insertando, pero no tiene sentido seguir este camino, por que escondería el problema conceptual en el manejo de los triggers que pareciera estas teniendo.

En SQL Server, los triggers se ejecutan siempre por lote, no por fila, a menos claro que el lote sea de una fila. Por ejemplo, si hicieramos algo así:

```
insert into Personas (...)
select ...
       from OtraTabla
```

Y `OtraTabla` tuviera 1000 filas, el trigger se ejecutará una sola vez, no 1000 veces. Esto nos obliga a repensar la lógica de todos los triggers, o bien cancelar en el mismo trigger, la inserción o actualización de más de una fila, que puede ser una alternativa, pero mucho mejor es repensar los triggers en función de `n` filas. En tu caso, podríamos reescribir todo de esta forma:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_aux ON personas AFTER INSERT 
AS 

    insert into auxiliar(ID, Nombre, Edad, Palabra)
    SELECT  I.ID,
            I.Nombre,
            I.Edad,
            CASE WHEN I.Edad > 18 THEN 'Es mayor de edad' ELSE 'Es menor de edad' END
            FROM inserted I
```

Estamos aprovechando la pseudo-tabla `inserted`, en los triggers de alta o actualización representa el conjunto de las filas que se están insertando o actualizando, con todas sus columnas, por lo que un simple `select/insert` resolvería todo sin tener que leer ninguna variable que ya vimos nos limitaría a procesar una única fila.